# JS - Iframe Height Resize

Tags: javascript, php

I have this

```
 <script>
     var calcHeight = function() {
       $('#iframe').height($(window).height());
     };
     $(document).ready(function() {
       calcHeight();
     });

     $(window).resize(function() {
       calcHeight();
     }).load(function() {
       calcHeight() ;
     }); </script>
```

The above JS just resizes the height. How to I edit the above JS and add to the calculated height 10px?

For example if the JS calculates 700px, I need to have the height as 710px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
<script>
 var calcHeight = function() {
   $('#iframe').height(10 + +$(window).height());
 };
 $(document).ready(function() {
   calcHeight();
 });

 $(window).resize(function() {
   calcHeight();
 }).load(function() {
   calcHeight() ;
 }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css calc() along with vh unit to do the calculations for you

```
iframe {
    height:calc(100vh + 10px);    
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kLn07Lqx/1/)

[calc() compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

[Viewport units compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

If you wish to continue using JS just add 10 to the returned height

```
$('#iframe').height($(window).height() + 10);
```